# Write Umlaute (ä, ü, ö) to serialport

Tags: shell, encoding, cmd, serial-port

I try to write german umlaute to a serialport.
When I do this in the dosshel with

```
echo öäü > com4
```

it is working correct.

When I create a txt-file with the content öäü and then do

```
copy test.txt com4
```

it is not working. The test.txt is saved as default ANSI Textfile (created with Notepad).

Can somebody help me, what I can change to get the textfile working?

Comment: Try using binary flag "copy /b"

Comment: @MarkSetchell - it doesn't also not work with flag /b.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it worth a try as the Help for COPY says it doesn't do "control characters" properly without the `/b` - and Microsoft may just consider umlauts to be control characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the text file with the encoding that the device expects. If "echo" from the shell works, that encoding is likely the terminal's code page, also known as "OEM code page." It's probably CP850 in your case.